# What is the opening tune in Four Lions?

Tags: soundtrack, four-lions

*Four Lions* (2010) has an opening tune. It can be listened to [here](https://youtu.be/IAarClRt8hY?t=3m20s) (if somewhat distorted).

It doesn't seem to be on the [IMDB soundtrack list](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1341167/soundtrack) for the film.

Does anyone know what the tune is, and who played it?

Comment: The video you have posted is blocked here in the US on Copyright grounds ...

Comment: @Paulster2 oh, apologies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's part of a Jeff beck tune, Nadia. Here is a version of it thou this one has some backing. [Nadia, Jeff Beck](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=drAv2FoYji8)

27/03/2017 - Here is the [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1341167/soundtrack) Soundtrack listing which does indeed include Jeff Beck's Nadia (performed by Jeff Beck) and written by Nitin Sawhney.